# React Native array map with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, reactjs, react-native

I need to map through a multidimensional array such as the following:

```
var array=[["1"],["3","8"],["4","8","3"],["4","8","3","9"],["1","8","3","9","2"],["6","8","3","9","2","1"],["4","8","3","9","2","11","2"]]
```

This code currently only maps through the 'columns' of the array.

```
var theValue = array.map((key, idx) => {
  if (key === this.state.active) {
    return <Main key={key + 'd'} dummy={true} />;
  } else {
    if (!this.state.restLayouts[idx]) {
      var onLayout = function(index, e) {
        var layout = e.nativeEvent.layout;
        this.setState((state) => {
          state.restLayouts[index] = layout;
          return state;
        });
      }.bind(this, idx);
    }
    return (
      <Main
        key={key}
        id={key}
        openVal={this.state.openVal}
        onLayout={onLayout}
        restLayout={this.state.restLayouts[idx]}
        onActivate={this.setState.bind(this, {
          active: key,
          activeInitialLayout: this.state.restLayouts[idx],
        })}
      />
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: how  should look the expected result?

Comment: Ok I guess I should have explained that. A grid. But each column may be different lengths since the array columns are of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of mapping a 2D array into a table. Dynamic width based on the amount of element per row using Flexbox:

```
<table style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  <tbody>
    {
      array.map(arr => {
        if (arr === this.state.active) {
          return (
            <tr style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
              {
                arr.map(datum => {
                  return (<th>{datum}</th>);
                }
              }
            </tr>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <tr style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-around'}}>
              {
                arr.map(datum => {
                  return (<td>{datum}</td>);
                }
              }
            </tr>
          );
        }
      ))
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there a way to do it that is more similar to the code I posted? Not necessarily React Native but how would you do it if the array was first assigned to a variable (theValue) and then using 'return'?

Comment: You can always assign the above code to a variable: `const theValue = (<table> ... </table>)`. It's just a demo of how you can do nested mapping, as I thought the question was about?

Comment: Yes it is, just not quite sure how to implement your example into my code is all.

Comment: I've expanded the syntax to use `return`s. Does this clear things out a little?

Comment: Yes that is a lot better although its really very different in React Native. There's no HTML so no tables and also you can't have the code like that inside JSX elements. It will just return errors. That's why I have it assigning to a variable, doing all the code calculation first and then the variable alone is returned inside the JSX. It does help though thanks.

Comment: React Native isn't all that different. Although you may have to create your own structure out of `View` and `Text`, you can still have nested Javascript Expressions within JSX.